# Very strange date conversion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I can see a really strange date conversion in my app. This is the code:

```
theDateString = [theDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

If `date` is `2007-12-31 00:00:00 +0100`
`theDateString` is `2008`

but if date is `2004-12-31 00:00:00 +0100`
`theDateString` is `2004.`

The method is `- (NSString *)stringFromDate:(NSDate *)date` in `NSDateFormatter` and it is a mac app.

The NSDateFormatter format is: `[theDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"Y"];`

Why ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@"y"` instead of `@"Y"`, because the capital "Y" specifies the year according to the "week of year". The 52nd week of 2007 ends in 2008, that's why it returns 2008 instead of 2007.

**Update:**
See: http://waracle.net/mobile/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/